# Template classes & operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, class-template

How do I go about overloading a template class like below?

```
template <class T>
const_iterator& List<T>::const_iterator::operator++()
{
  current = current->next;
  return *this;
}

template <class T>
const_iterator List<T>::const_iterator::operator++(int)
{
  const_iterator old = *this;
  ++( *this );
  return old;
}
```

I am getting errors like below:

```
List.cpp:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token
List.cpp:23: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘List’
List.cpp:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token
List.cpp:35: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘List’
```

Comment: `typename List<T>::const_iterator& List<T>::const_iterator::operator++()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::const_iterator& List<T>::const_iterator::operator++()
```

At the time the return type is specified, you're not inside the so-called lexical scope of `List<T>`. And since there is no type `const_iterator` in the enclosing scope, you get an error (though that one could manifest itself a little bit better, IMHO).

Another option for C++11 might be a trailing return type:

```
template<class T>
auto List<T>::const_iterator::operator++()
    -> const_iterator&
{
  // ...
}
```

However, the best idea would be to just define these things inline in the class itself. Do you have a special reason for the out-of-class definitions?

Comment: FWIW, all of GCC 4.6, 4.7 and clang 3.1 complain that "const_iterator is not a type". It seems the OP is using GCC 4.5.

Comment: I am using the version of GCC that OSX updates to.
And the reason I am not building inside the class is because this is part of a homework assignment.

Comment: Also, quick question while I wait to be able to accept this as the answer. How exactly would I format something like this as well with just a T as the type? `template <class T>
T& List<T>::const_iterator::retrieve()
{ // return a reference to the corresponding element in the list.                                                              
  return current->data;
}`

Comment: @jordaninternets: What exactly do you mean? Your code seems fine, although I'd definitly change that to `T const&`, since that's the whole point of a `const_iterator`. ;)